# IFTTT filter code to skip action if switchbot activated within last hour

Tags: alexa, ifttt

So what I am trying to do is implement some filter code in an IFTTT applet that will skip the action if it was already performed within the last hour.

It's for triggering my heating which is a dumb system with a switchbot button pusher. How I want it to work is for an Alexa phrase to trigger the push of the button, but if that already happened within the last hour I was wondering is it possible to skip the action under that condition.

Comment: I wonder if you can play with logic blocks and timers. Here is something to get your thoughts flowing https://ifttt.com/search/query/logic

Comment: Through sheer dumb luck I've figured it out through the logic blocks in apilio, thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to the forum, @Chrisiuy . Glad it worked for you. FYI, if you like someone's comment or answer, you can click the up arrow at the left of the answer/comment and that will give them a few points.